# is it possible to avoid re-run configure and do incremental builds when some sub-makefiles has been changed?

Tags: makefile, configure, autoconf

GCC defines the sub-makefile as Make-lang.in, and it contains:

```
tiny_OBJS = \
    tiny/tiny1.o \
    $(END)
```

When I add some component, I changed it to:

```
tiny_OBJS = \
    tiny/tiny1.o \
    tiny/tiny-token.o \
    tiny/tiny-lexer.o \
    $(END)
```

So all the rest is untouched, and I want make an incremental builds on those 2 new files and don't re-compiler anything else. The problem is that if I don't re-run the configure, it gives me some un-declaration problems, seems the new file had not been recognized.

I'm not sure whether I did something wrong or the autoconf is designed to re-run configure at this situation. If it is, can I have some hooks to avoid it? as re-compiler everything takes too long.

Comment: Are you talking about building GCC itself?  Otherwise, I don't understand what you mean by "GCC defines".  And if you are talking about building GCC, then is that actually important to the question?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes I'm building the GCC, and it names the sub-makefile extension with suffix .in. I think that might mean something so I put it there

Answer (score 1):

If you change a *.in file, you have to re-run *something* because the *.in file has to be converted into the real makefile.

First, any typical autotools makefile (such as generated by automake) has a rule in it for doing this automatically so you don't have to do anything by hand: if you run `make` and it sees that your `.in` file has been changed, it will automatically update it for you in the most efficient way possible then restart the `make`.

If your makefiles don't have such a rule you'll have to do it by hand.  You certainly do not need to re-run autoconf to generate a new `configure`, and you don't even need to run `configure`.  You can run `config.status` which just rebuilds the output files using the existing configuration.  See: https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.71/html_node/config_002estatus-Invocation.html